# Quick file view in xcode?

Tags: xcode5

I'm using xcode 5.1. Is there a way to easily create a code editor window for code that I want to see but don't want included in my project? Sometimes I want to view a SO code snippet  where the lines of code extend offscreen. Right now I copy the snippet to the clipboard, paste it into a new TextEdit window, save the file with a .m file type, and then double-click the saved file. Then I can see it with all of xcode's syntax highlighting, etc.

Is there a way I can do this in fewer steps?

Thanks